# Mapping a generic stored procedure for CRUD in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm developing a MVC4 project with EF5 and I've created a generic stored procedure for CRUD operations on users table.

```
spUsers @opt, @id, @password, @name, @lastname, @birthdate

if @opt = 1 INSERT ...
if @opt = 2 UPDATE ...
if @opt = 3 DELETE ...
```

Reasons I'm doing this in one stored procedure is to avoid doing them into three separated stored procedures and acumulate too much stored procedures for others tables.

My question is, is it possible to mapping user class for insert, update and delete operations with that generic stored procedure using EF designer and then manually provide @opt value?

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea. When SQL Server create an execution plan for your proc, it will create it with the first time it's executed. So you do an INSERT and then a SELECT with a naff plan. My question is: why use procedures when EF is specifically built for you to manipulate the tables directly?

Comment: David you're right, it's a bad idea for simple CRUD operations tables, I was thinking about this for business logic situations when it's needed to put some logic into stored procedures in whose case it seems is better to execute stored procedures explicitly and not attach them to a particular class, I guess.